# Could anyone tell me about the differences between Application Composer and Step Functions?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions, aws-serverless

They look pretty similar, both provide a visual interface to compose lambda functions, data sources and sinks, etc. to serverless applications.

By comparing the information from aws website I failed to tell the differences between those two products. Could anyone help to give me some insights about the differences?

I have tried read the docs and use cases of both products but failed to find the differences. I would like to know when I should choose Application Composer and when move to Step Functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Application composer will help you create your serverless application. You will put your services together, and then you can deploy them.

The step function does completely different things. It orchestrates already-created services. In a step function, you will set how/when you want to execute your steps (lambda function, dynamodb integrations, etc..), and then you can execute the step function anytime you want.